# How to find the job which abended on X SchedTime in TWS(In command line)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, tivoli-work-scheduler

I want the jobs which are abended before 11 day from today(SchedTime) in TWS

Like I use

conman ss @#@+state=abend  to know the jobs in abended status
But now I want the job which are in abeded status from last 11 days in current plan in TWS

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
+started=0000 5/21/2017,2359 5/31/2017
```

this will show job started from May 21st at 00:00 to May 31st at 23:59

Comment: but just want for a particular time  like job abend at 20:30 on 04 Jan 2020?